# Converting an abstract return type to a concrete implementation

Tags: rust

I am using a function (from Cloudflare workers, if that's relevant) which has an abstract return type: `pub fn timezone(&self) -> impl chrono::TimeZone`. I'm trying to get a string representation of this function's output. The trait it's refering to is [`TimeZone`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.31/chrono/offset/trait.TimeZone.html).

There is another crate, [chrono-tz](https://crates.io/crates/chrono-tz) which provides implementors of the `TimeZone` trait. Specifically, it provides a [`Tz`](https://docs.rs/chrono-tz/0.8.4/chrono_tz/enum.Tz.html) enum which can be converted to a string.

However, I can't work out how to get create `Tz` object from my original `impl TimeZone`. More generally, is there any way to convert an abstract return type to another specific struct which implements that same trait? I realise this might not make much sense in all contexts, but I seem to be missing something pretty important, because this seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: There is no general way to do this for arbitrary traits and concrete types. If there is a way, it's specific to `TimeZone` and `Tz`.

Comment: For debugging, or…? Describe the greater goal.

Comment: @Ry- No, I want to serialise it and add it to a JSON payload for a HTTP request. So yes, I really do need the timezone as a string.

Comment: So you need the name of the timezone? What provides the `timezone` function (because you’ll need its help for that)?

Comment: Thanks, you're right: it's the Clourflare worker crate (crates.io/crates/worker) which also provides a timezone_name function! Duh!

Comment: @JohnKugelman Technically, there is a way (if not recommended) using specialization.

Comment: Hi @ChayimFriedman can you elaborate? While the specific issue that was causing me problems is fixed, my question was more general, so an answer on this would be relevant.

Comment: Don't go throughout the specialization route. It was a technical nit.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman maybe it is, but the fact is that if the worker crate hadn't provided a timezone_name function, I wouldn't have been able to get the name. What are my options in a situation like this? I realise specialisation may be poor practice, but there still are situations in which something like this is needed, much like unsafe.